# Objective-C: Change an image from a separate class

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I have looked around for an answer to this with no avail, so I hope I am not asking an answered question.

I have two classes (ClassA and ClassB), both connected to UIViewControllers that are linked via a segue. ClassA contains a UIImage named backgroundImage. My goal is to change ClassA's background image from within ClassB.

In ClassB.h I have tried:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) ClassA *mainView;
```

And in ClassB.m I tried changing the background image via:

```
@synthesize mainView;
//Then inside button click I tried:
[mainView.backgroundImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"newImage.jpg"]];
```

Obviously this did not work since I am not setting the image to the same ClassA that is being used in the app.
I know I'm missing something obvious, thanks in advance!

Comment: Do one thing take a string in the AppDelegate and change that string from class B . Use that imagestring in the class A .Let me know if you have any questions

Comment: If there is a valid instance of mainView this should work.

Comment: mainView is not the instance that is being segued, otherwise this code would work.

Comment: You could delegate it. You can have ClassB calling a delegate method in ClassA.

Comment: How you have assign referance to ClassA *mainView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the **Protocol mechanism** to satisfy your requirements

Implementation is as bellow

In **AppDelegate.h** file of project

```
@protocol ImageChangeDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
    -(void)ChangeImage;
@end


@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
}
@property (nonatomic,strong) id<ImageChangeDelegate> delegateImageChange;
```

In **AppDelegate.m** file of project

```
@synthesize delegateImageChange;
```

Now In **.h file of Class B**

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface EventGuestListViewController : UIViewController
{
   AppDelegate* appDelegate;
}
-(void)ChangeBackgroundOfClassA;
```

Now In **.m file of Class B**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
}
```

Now in method of changing BGs

```
 -(void)ChangeBackgroundOfClassA
 {
     [appDelegate.delegateImageChange ChangeImage];
 }
```

Now Implements the Protocol in Class A to change the Background.

Now In **.h file of Class A**

```
 #import "AppDelegate.h"

 @interface EventGuestListViewController : UIViewController <ImageChangeDelegate>
 {
    IBOutlet UIImageView* imageBGClassA;
    AppDelegate* appDelegate;
 }
```

Now In **.m file of Class A**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    appDelegate.delegateImageChange = self; //Here you need to set the delegate to 'self' to call then Custom Protocol method
}

-(void)ChangeImage
{
     imageBGClassA.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"newImage.jpg"];
}
```

In Class B once `-(void)ChangeBackgroundOfClassA` call the delegate method call which is implement on Class A and the background Image will surly change

This is work with me

It may help you !!!

Comment: ClassB is choosing from several saved image files, so I need to pass a string with the file location, where in this code is ClassB providing a string?

Comment: you can pass string with the protocol methos `-(void)ChangeImage` i.e. `-(void)ChangeImage:(NSString *)string`. And pass string according to your requirements

Comment: Thank you, I will try this later tonight. If it works I will accept your answer to be the best one. Cheers

Comment: I ended up using a different solution, but you answer was very well described and efficient. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use the same "mainView" instance of ClassA to navigate to `ClassA View Controller`.

Comment: Could I get an example on accessing ClassA's ViewController?

Answer (score 0):

Should try out delegate mechanism.It will allow you to call a method in classA from classB.
In that method change the background image of classA from classB's call to delegate

Answer (score 0):

You can try any of two ways:
1) Using the delegation. Passing the delegate while loading ClassB.
2) Using the NotificationCenter and change the mainView Image by calling the notification from Class B.

Harry.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this task easily using Custom Delegates or Notifications . I will explain it to you using Notification . Let there be two classes - Class-A & Class-B

In the Class-A add a Notification like this

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(changeImage)
                                             name:@"ImageChangeNotification"
                                           object:nil];
```

also create the selector in the Class-A

```
 -(void)changeImage
   {
       [yourImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YouImageName.png"]];
   }
```

What left is just to post this Notification from anywhere within the whole project . In our case let it be Class-B

```
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ImageChangeNotification" object:nil];
```

Comment: Where in ClassA am I calling NSNotificationCenter, and how is ClassB deciding what file name the new image should be?

Comment: In classA NSNotificationCenter should be called in the ViewDidLoad , also you can post any object along with the Notification at the time of posting NSNotification in the classB to the ClassA . Hope you  got my point .

Comment: so by posting any object, where you have object:nil, I could send a string with the new image name?